# Why is my colour temperature suddenly warmer on my monitor?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, color-profiles

I uninstalled and reinstalled the **AMD Radeon drivers and software** for my monitor because Ethminer and Phoenix miner couldn't detect my single **RX 580 8GB** graphics card.

I got Phoenix and Ethminer working for a couple days, then on day 3 my monitor colours were suddenly warmer. I checked **windows color management** to make sure that my colour profile didn't revert back to that really warm Samsung colour profile, but no, it was still the default **sRGB IEC61966-2.1**.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

**AMD Radeon software** that comes with your driver may sometimes automatically change your colour temperature by itself when you first install it. Since you reinstalled 3 days ago it will count as a fresh install.

1. Access the **AMD Radeon Software** by right-clicking your desktop to open the context menu

[image: Context Menu]

2. Click the **gear** to the top right
3. Click **Display** to the top left
4. Next to **Global Display** select your monitor, in this example I am changing Display 2 (my centre monitor)
5. Turn off the **Custom Color** toggle to a grey colour, if it is on it is a red colour
   [image: AMD Radeon Software]

Your monitor colour should return to the normal neutral sRGB colours, they appear cooler in colour temperature.